# octopress plugin for CDF reader?

Tags: cdf-format

I am looking for a way to [embed CDFs](http://www.wolfram.com/cdf/adopting-cdf/deploying-cdf/web-delivery.html) in [octopress](http://octopress.org/docs/plugins/) blogs. Looks like there are a lot of moving parts such as [Jekyll](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll), Liquid, and [Pygments](http://pygments.org/). I'd be grateful for a native trailguide through the jungle.

Comment: Does Octopress allow JS or/and iframes?

Comment: This is not a comment on what is on-topic on this site, but you might have better luck if you ask people who work with octopress and point them to the [CDF embedding instructions](http://www.wolfram.com/cdf/adopting-cdf/deploying-cdf/web-delivery.html)

Comment: Thanks, @Szabolcs.  I have a thread going with octopress, too, but so far it's produced silence.  I thought I'd ping here in case one of our MMA experts has solved the problem.  Apologies if the question is on the fringe.